# Perforce merge from a branch to a label

Tags: perforce, perforce-integrate

I am trying to merge codes in a private branch to a label. But I don't know how to do it.
Do I need to make a new branch out of the label and use branch mapping to do it?

thx

Comment: What client tool(s) are you using? P4V? The `p4` command? Other?

Comment: A label is a snapshot of the revisions you currently have in your workspace. It doesn't have to do with branching or merging.

Comment: In general, you use the 'p4 integrate' command, but there are lots of variations and options. What integrate command have you tried, and what problems did you encounter?

Comment: Sorry guys for not checking the answers. I have been too busy lately.

Comment: Here is what I am doing right now. So I create a dev branch and using a branch spec to merge and integrate. BTW, I am using p4v. After the "p4 integrate -b branch_spec_name" I see "no files opened". None of the files get integrated. Does anyone knows why? thx

Comment: In the branch spec, I map the source branch (space) depot tree location of the dev branch. Is this correct? thx